# Stripe API issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I get the following error when I use the Stripe API for Rails.

[image]

The error occurs when:

- I use the token with parameters,
- I directly create the map without parameters in Rails console. The code only worked when I used the code below. -

```
Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_51OxaxrHv50QCG0VIMSQ1gFDxuQpV5V2T2qsGb2GklU4Fq2WJszkD2Tq0z9zVI6ZL.....'
Stripe::Token.create({
  card: {
    number: '4242424242424242',
    exp_month: '5',
    exp_year: '2024',
    cvc: '314',
  },
})
```

I have used the following function to create a map with parameters. -

```
  def create_card_token(params)
    Stripe::Token.create({
      card: {
        number: params[:card_number].to_s,
        exp_month: params[:exp_month].to_s,
        exp_year: params[:exp_year].to_s,
        cvc: params[:cvc].to_s,
      },
    })
  end
```

Can anyone help me fix this error or tell me where I am going wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the support URL shared in the error: https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-apis Sending RAW PAN (card data) to Stripe APIs has additional requirements and requires approval from Stripe.

If your account is already approved to send raw card details then you'd likely want to check if your `Stripe` instance is using the correct API key when you make the API call by setting card details from `params`

Alternatively, a better approach to storing payment methods is to use SetupIntents API as recommended here: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-and-reuse